# Extract Text in tag STRONG

Tags: python, scrapy

Is it possible to extract the text (Hello World) in the strong tag using only CSS **NOT** xpath

`<h4 class="inline"> <a href="https://example.com/example"><strong>Hello World</strong></a></h4>`

Comment: If you want to use "only CSS", what does this have to do with Python?

Comment: What does "get the text(Hello World) into the strong tag" mean?

Comment: I mean extract the string "Hello Word" using scrapy

Comment: OK, and what does "using only CSS" mean if you're actually using scrapy?

Comment: I mean ,  ex response.css('div.quote'):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
response.css(h4.inline a::text).get()
```

or

```
response.css(h4.inline a strong::text).get()
```